# Can't delete a folder or file with FileUtils.rm because of @unlink_internal

Tags: ruby

Running `FileUtils.rm(a_folder)` is giving me the error:

`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ unlink_internal - a_folder`

`a_folder` is definitely valid, I actually got there through

```
Dir.foreach(path) do |f|
  if f != '.' && f != '..' 
    FileUtils.rm(f)
  end
end
```

Same problem for `rm_rf` and `remove_dir`.

Comment: `FileUtils.rm` [does not operate on directories](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm). You said `FileUtils.remove_dir` doesn't work either but did not specify the error you receive for that method. So troubleshoot it; is it really a directory, not a soft/hardlink? Is it returned by `Dir.foreach(path) { |f| puts f if Dir.exist?(f) }`?

Comment: Hm for some reason `FileUtils.remove_dir` just worked. Not sure what I did differently this time (or rather what I did definitely wrong last time). Thanks.